# Full searchable-index. How to to extract into readable version

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-rest-api, 2016, crawling

I would like to extract the searchable index of selected sites from the intranet (sharepoint server 2016). I have a target to create custom search using vectorstore where I need to have full SHP2016 search-index. I tried with elasticsearch custom connectors but it failed. Is that possible to export the search-index of 200 (content of pages, attachements etc.) sites into readble version like json, csv or even pandas type (using python, ex. shareplum)?

After that I would like to load this/these files with python and preprocess them properly -> in order to keep an appropriate schema (url, title, site, type, body content, last modified date etc.)

Is that possible to accomplish it using powershell or admin SHP web panel?

Many thanks for your kind help in advance